# How to write an SQL query that uses wild-card map to do transformation

Tags: sql, wildcard

I have a source table A with a number of columns. I want to do a transformation of the source table to a target table. I would like to have a mapping table with same columns as the source table A and with rows that make up the translations.

Here is an example of the table A:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
aktie   ja         2
aktie   nej        3
obli    ja         2
```

and here is the mapping table

```
COL1    COL2    COL3        TRANSFORM
aktie   ja      NULL            3
aktie   NULL    NULL            4
```

Now, the idea is to join the source table with the mapping and get the transformed value returned. The use of NULL should serve as a wildcard. So my desired result should be that the first row in table A would match the first row in the mapping table and return the value 3

For the second row - and here is my challenge - I want it to match the second row in the mapping table because it is NOT matched by rows that have a value already (which would result in the transformed value 3) and as the second mapping row has NULL in column two, it should be treated as a wildcard (although taking into account other rows in the mapping table as well).

My first attempt would be something like

```
select A.*, m.res
from tab1 A
inner join mapping m on t.col1 = isnull(m.col1, t.col1) 
                     and t.col2 = isnull(m.col2, t.col2)
and ...
```

but the problem is that the `isnull(..,..)` will match everything and not only return matches except the listed possible values that would result in a different transformation.

I am looking for a generic solution that would Work for any table with any number of columns, not only this particular table-layout mentioned here.

I have been thinking a lot about this and cannot really seem to come up with the solution, so please help :)

Comment: Which platform are you using?  For my idea it would be best if it was SQL Server, Oracle, or DB2 (won't work on mysql)

Comment: Preferably, it should Work on both SQL server or Oracle, and if your idea only Works on one of them, SQL Server is preferred

Comment: I'm not following the issue you think you see with your idea: "the problem is that the isnull(..,..) will match everything [...]."  `isnull(m.col1, t.col1)` (or `coalesce(m.col1, t.col1)`) will return `t.col1` if `m.col1` is null, else `m.col1`.  How does that result in different behavior than treating null as a wildcard would do?

Comment: The idea is that is should be treated as a wildcard but with the twist that it shoud only be treated as a wild Card if there is nothing else that matches. In the example, I only want to get the transformation to return 4 if the source table has col1 = aktie and col2 is anything BUT "ja" . And in the general case it should be anything BUT the other values in the mapping table's col2. I hope I explain it better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using a CTE (will work on SQL Server and Oracle)

```
WITH Map3 as 
( -- TRANSFORM WILL BE NULL IF A MATCH WAS NOT MADE
   SELECT T1.COL1, T1.COL2, T1.COL3, M.TRANSFORM
   FROM Table1 T1
   LEFT JOIN Mapping M ON T1.COL1 = M.COL1 
                      AND T1.COL2 = M.COL2
                      AND T1.COL3 = COALESCE(M.COL3, T1.COL3)
), Map2 as
(
   SELECT T1.COL1, T1.COL2, T1.COL3, COALESCE(T1.TRANSFORM,M.TRANSFORM)
   FROM Map3 T1
   LEFT JOIN Mapping M ON T1.COL1 = M.COL1 
                      AND T1.COL2 = COALESCE(M.COL2, T1.COL2)
                      AND T1.TRANSFORM IS NULL
)
SELECT * 
FROM Map2
```

I believe it is clear how this works and how to "extend" this to more columns.

---

If you can't use a CTE this is functionally the same and can be nested as far as you like:

```
SELECT T1.COL1, T1.COL2, T1.COL3, COALESCE(T1.TRANSFORM,M.TRANSFORM)
FROM (
   -- TRANSFORM WILL BE NULL IF A MATCH WAS NOT MADE
   SELECT T1.COL1, T1.COL2, T1.COL3, M.TRANSFORM
   FROM Table1 T1
   LEFT JOIN Mapping M ON T1.COL1 = M.COL1 
                      AND T1.COL2 = M.COL2
                      AND T1.COL3 = COALESCE(M.COL3, T1.COL3)
) T1
LEFT JOIN Mapping M ON T1.COL1 = M.COL1 
                   AND T1.COL2 = COALESCE(M.COL2, T1.COL2)
                   AND T1.TRANSFORM IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi Hogan, it works on the example I have given, but I would like it to work in general. If I change the 2nd row in the mapping table to 
NULL  NULL  2
I would like it to match the third row of the source table. In your example there is not coalesce around col1. I tried to apply coalesce around col1, but that doesn't work, so does it mean that I would have to write a Map2, Map3, ...ManN for N columns for this to work? And how would that perform for tables with many columns and rows?

Comment: @codermaden yes you would need 1-n sub queries.... Can't think of a better way to do it.

Comment: Crap. Well, that was what I was trying to avoid, but if you come to the same conclusion - and noone else has come up with a nicer solution - I suppose that is the only way. Luckily, it can be generated, so now I am just wondering how efficient it will be for a source table with 100,000 rows and for instance 50 columns.... I guess a stress test will tell :) Thanks for your help, Hogan!

Comment: Let me think about it.. at those sizes there are probably some optimization suggestions I can make....

Comment: Well, define small :) It can vary, but often it would be less 1000 rows. There are examples of 10,000 rows - but that might be handled otherwise if performance is killed