# Partial wildcard NULL join in SQL Server exploding out data for easier use

Tags: sql-server, join, wildcard

I've got a problem which I have a solution to, but I suspect it is not the **best** solution.
([possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199573/how-to-write-an-sql-query-that-uses-wild-card-map-to-do-transformation))

Suppose you have data and logic from some crazy people:

```
ImportantNumber   Entity    MappingCode     
---------------------------------------
1                 A         Ted
1                 NULL      Fred
1                 C         Ned
```

Where ImportantNumber = 1 maps to "Ted" if Entity = "A", "Ned" if Entity = "C", and "Fred" otherwise - IE the specific matches take precedence.

Suppose you have a table full of entities, from A-Z. You want to explode this table out to contain all mappings for other joins and logic. (For amusement, I have several of these columns....grr...)

My solution is this, however, I'm sure that there should be a more efficient way of doing it:

Test Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    ImportantNumber varchar(1),
    Entity varchar(1),
    Mapping varchar(4)
)

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
('1', 'A', 'Ted'),
('1', null, 'Fred'),
('1', 'C', 'Ned')

CREATE TABLE #Entities (Entity varchar(1))
INSERT INTO #Entities VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E') --etc
```

Example with test data:

```
--Use a CTE to create the specific matches
;WITH matches AS
(
SELECT
    t.ImportantNumber,
    e.Entity,
    t.Mapping
FROM
    #Entities e
INNER JOIN
    #temp t
ON
    e.Entity = t.Entity
)
/*
Get the specific matches and UNION them with the NULL entry 
which excludes all Entities in the matches CTE
*/
SELECT
    ImportantNumber,
    Entity,
    Mapping
FROM
    matches
UNION ALL
SELECT
    t.ImportantNumber,
    e.Entity,
    t.Mapping
FROM
    #temp t
LEFT JOIN
    #Entities e
ON
    t.Entity IS NULL -- all Entities will be matched against the NULL column
WHERE
    e.Entity NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Entity FROM matches)
```

Note that this works for a single "ImportantNumber" - this will need to be changed to a LEFT JOIN for multiple - but I'm still working on that

Expected output should be:

```
ImportantNumber   Entity    MappingCode     
---------------------------------------
1                 A         Ted
1                 C         Ned
1                 B         Fred
1                 D         Fred
1                 E         Fred
etc for F-Z
```

Comment: I don't understand the expected result, can you post the result you want in examples of what must and mustn't be done?

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci added, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be an alternate solution that works with multiple `ImportantNumber`.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    ImportantNumber varchar(1),
    Entity varchar(1),
    Mapping varchar(4)
)

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
('1', 'A', 'Ted'),
('1', null, 'Fred'),
('1', 'C', 'Ned'),

('2', 'B', 'Ted2'),
('2', null, 'Fred2'),
('2', 'D', 'Ned2')

CREATE TABLE #Entities (Entity varchar(1))
INSERT INTO #Entities VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E') --etc

;WITH Missing AS
(
SELECT
    t.ImportantNumber,
    t.Entity,
    t.Mapping
FROM
    #temp t
WHERE 
    t.Entity IS NULL
)

SELECT
    t.ImportantNumber,
    e.Entity,
    t.Mapping
FROM
    #Entities e
INNER JOIN
    #temp t
ON
    e.Entity = t.Entity
UNION ALL
SELECT
    t.ImportantNumber,
    e.Entity,
    t.Mapping
FROM
    Missing t
CROSS JOIN #Entities e  -- all Entities will be matched with the NULL column    
LEFT JOIN #temp tt ON e.Entity = tt.Entity
      AND t.ImportantNumber = tt.ImportantNumber
WHERE
    tt.Entity IS NULL   -- exclude rows which has matching entity
```